# Возможно ли на программном уровне менять цвет в ресурсах колорс?

Tags: java, android, value

Подскажите возможно ли на программном уровне поменять цвет в ресурсах сolors.Допустим у меня есть

```
 <color name="main_color">#081029</color>
```

Я хочу что бы при нажатии на switchCompat менялся код именно в этом блоке.К примеру, если пользователь нажимает switchCompat  то тогда main_color получает такие вот значения.

```
<color name="main_color">#ffffff</color>
```

У меня стоит такая задача, я хочу что б когда пользователь нажимал на switchCompat у него менялось цветовое оформление приложение (как пример есть дневная и ночная тема).Вариант где

```
 Resources resources = getResources();
 int second_color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorTextSecondary);
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
 relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(second_color);
```

не сильно подходит, потому что это привязывает меня к id слоев. Поэтому я и хотел узнать есть ли другой способ как можно менять цвета оформления.

Comment: Конечно нет. У вас [XY проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/276430), лучше опишите основную задачу

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Comment: @Deniss Zadorozhniy, полюбопытствуйте. Крайне просто расписано о светлой и темной теме https://devcolibri.com/how-to-implement-day-night-mode/

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Лучше разделить не `colors` на value и value-night, как в статье, а разделить `themes` https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark